# Weird issue in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm facing a weird issue in `UILabel`. If you look at the Image there is a border appears on right corner of my `UILabel`. I m subclassing `UILabel` to add some string properties.

This issue is  inconsistent. happening in  **Landscape or in Portrait**.

Anyone faced such issue/ What could be the issue? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

I m sub classing it in below way:

```
@interface MyLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strObjID;

@end

@implementation MyLabel
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
}

@end
```

this is how I add in `UITableViewCell`

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *strId = @"layoutCell";
MyLabel *lblRecord;
        UITableViewCell *layoutCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strId];
        if (layoutCell == nil) {
            layoutCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strId];
            [layoutCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
      lblRecord = [[MyLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 10, 980,70)];
     [layoutCell addSubview:lblRecord];
        }
        [lblRecord.textLabel setText:[arrListOfLayouts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return layoutCell;
    }
```

Comment: can you paste code for subclassing uilabel..

Comment: It looks like a scroll...

Comment: @Szu I m not using any scroll inside Label

Comment: @FahimParkar Snippet added

Comment: Im damn sure that is not a label, its a UITextView. Anyway how you adding the label?

Comment: I am creating sample project and testing it...

Comment: Are u sure this is UIlabel

Comment: show us your code how you are writing data for it... also show us related UILabel code...

Comment: I m sure it's label. this issue is not happening in Retina version of simulator

Comment: @iDev : code please related to this label...

Comment: change `[self addSubview:lblRecord];` to `[layoutCell addSubview:lblRecord];` & remove if condition...

Comment: `[self addSubview:lblRecord];` Are you sure with this line of code? I think it should be `[layoutCell.contentView addSubview:lblRecord];`

Comment: @FahimParkar Issue  still persist

Comment: @LouisZhu This issue happens only on non retina simulator

Comment: Why are you adding `lblRecord` as a subview of itself? `[lblRecord addSubview:lblRecord];` Also, that is clearly not your whole `UILabel` subclass, as that code won't even run (you're not returning `self` in your `initWithFrame` method). If it's just an oversight and you forgot to paste that line that's fine, but if you're doing other things to your subclassed label, you need to show them.